# Using Vlookup and avoiding the repeating value while fetching data from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I am using Vlookup to fetch a list of cities for a given country present in another sheet but in the same workbook. The problem I facing is if I am looking for all the cities from India and Delhi is present is the 7th row so the `Vlookup` will give me the first 7 cells as Delhi (I removed the `$` in the range input so that the starting row always changes) similarly ahead I will get recurring cells from the lookup range when the country is not India. How can I avoid that without using the `Query` function?

Running the whole process and then using distinct to get the list is too inefficient for my project and the process slows down tremendously.

Comment: @player0 Hey I can't share the copy of my sheet but I can make a dummy sheet which I will share with you. My desired output is that I should get only distinct cities. Actually, I have a drop down with country names and for the countries, I want to filter the dropdown of city names with only cities from that specific country. I used Vlookup with lookup value from the drop-down selection and with the sheet consisting list of countries, cities, and hotels present I want to fetch filtered result for the subsequent drop downs.

Comment: dummy it is then, pls do so